# How to make Extended Asset Browser feature turned on by default in 3.0?

Tags: collections, source-code, asset-browser, asset

Blender's 3.0 release is awesome especially the asset browser. However, I notice that I couldn't mark a Collection as an asset. In previous beta releases you could turn on *Extended Asset Browser* feature in Preferences that would solve the problem, but we don't have this feature in 3.0 stable.

I found that this feature is still in the code, but is not activated. In order to activate it i edited the source file named *space_userpref.py*, in class *USERPREF_PT_experimental_new_features* on line 2275, which has *"use_extended_asset_browser"*, i added @classmethod:

```
class USERPREF_PT_experimental_new_features(ExperimentalPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "New Features"
 
     @classmethod
        def poll(cls, _context):
            return True
        
    def draw(self, context):
        self._draw_items(
            context, (
                ({"property": "use_sculpt_vertex_colors"}, "T71947"),
                ({"property": "use_sculpt_tools_tilt"}, "T82877"),
                ({"property": "use_extended_asset_browser"}, ("project/view/130/", "Project Page")),
                ({"property": "use_override_templates"}, ("T73318", "Milestone 4")),
            ),
        )
```

After that *Extended Asset Browser* feature has appeared in *Preferences - Experimental*, and i can now chose collections from Asset Brwoser's filter menu:

[image]

But the problem is when i close Blender and then open it again *Extended Asset Browser* feature turns off by default, so i need to go back to *Preferences* and turn it on again. Is there a way to make it turned on by default, so i won't need to go to *Preferences* every time?

Comment: Hello ! Wouldn't it be less bothersome to use the 3.1 alpha release ?

Comment: Hi! I had a lot of issues with non-stable versions resolving in Blender crashes, which i don't have in stable release. So for my work i need it to be 3.0 for now and get those collections working for asset library to use. But it can be a good option for others!

Comment: Makes sense. Can you confirm that the option to enable extended asset browser does stay in the preferences panel, even though it automatically turns off every time you reopen Blender ?

Comment: Yes, it does stay in the preferences panel and i do Save Preferences, but check box is empty when i reopen Blender.

Comment: Maybe a simple addon that would turn on this value on startup would do. Have you considered it ?

Comment: That is a good idea. I guess i will have to do so, if there are no othere simple solution.
Thank you for yout help and time!

Comment: This handler will do I think : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.load_post